# setBarcodeFormats(Barcode.QR_CODE) does not work

Tags: android, qr-code, google-vision

I'm using Google Play Vision API to detect qr codes. I'm not interested in other formats, so I'm trying to use that API call to speed up detection. It works fine if I'm calling it as `setBarcodeFormats(Barcode.ALL_FORMATS)`, it detects qr codes with format 256 (QR_CODE), but if I'm initializing it as `setBarcodeFormats(Barcode.QR_CODE)`, it does not detect anything. Here's some code snippets:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    ...
    barcodeDetector = BarcodeDetector.Builder(applicationContext).setBarcodeFormats(Barcode.ALL_FORMATS).build()
    ...


private inner class ImageReaderOnImageAvailableListenerImpl : ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener {
    override fun onImageAvailable(reader: ImageReader) {
        val image = reader.acquireNextImage()
        val buffer = image.planes[0].buffer;
        val bitmap: Bitmap? = if (buffer.hasArray()) {
            BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(buffer.array(), buffer.arrayOffset(), buffer.remaining(), null);
        } else {
            val byteArray = ByteArray(buffer.remaining())
            buffer.get(byteArray)
            BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteArray, 0, byteArray.size, null);
        }

        val barcodes = barcodeDetector.detect(Frame.Builder().setBitmap(bitmap).build())
        image.close()
        this@QrCodeCaptureActivity.imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap)

        if (barcodes.size() > 0) {
            for (index in 0 until barcodes.size()) {
                val barcode = barcodes.valueAt(index)
                logd("barcode $index: ${barcode.format} ${barcode.valueFormat} ${barcode.rawValue}")
            }
        } else {
            logd("no barcodes (${image.width}x${image.height})")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have noticed this too, I think its a bug. I just ended up going with all